# Finding a string in a .txt and getting the line contents in C++

Tags: c++, file

im looking for a way to open a text file and find a certain string and then get the line it is on, then get the contents of that line. I can't find any help for this. Also i need to use C++ and preinstalled libs ... etc. anything that wont work on a mac or isn't preinstalled with c++.... I may be able to use small other libs...

Comment: There's plenty of information on how to do this. What have you tried?

Comment: Google, Stackoverflow well i cant find anything? A link would be helpful atleast....

Comment: You're going to have to combine bits and pieces, no ones going to give you the solution to your exact problem. But the fileIO docs on cplusplus.com ( http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/ ) are probably adequate for reading the file and of course the `find` method to see if string A contains string B is well documented. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
open a filestream

while filestream is NOT at End Of File
    get a line of the file into a temp string
    search the temp string for the keyword
    if the keyword is in it
        thats your line, exit the loop
    else keep looping
```

hopefully that's a big enough hint for you.

Comment: Omg thank you! I would of never guessed... bad algorythming... Thnx